# how to convert metafont created fonts to PS 1 fonts

Tags: metafont, postscript

I have a font (for the script of my language) which was created using metafont. But as is the usual problem with 8-bit fonts it does not scale well. So I have had to create multiple tfm files for different sizes and use them appropriately. Is there a way to convert these fonts to PS 1 fonts that look good with scaling so that I do not have to bother creating a different font for each size I am interested in?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to tex,sx,  The metatype1 tool will convert from metapost output to type 1; it's not quite the same, but may provide a pathway.  Information on CTAN at https://ctan.org/pkg/metatype1